# Flutter StreamBuilder what is the scope to your children

Tags: flutter, dart

As I understand the logic it would be that if I have a StreamBuilder that has a "FirebaseUser" stream, it will be executed every time the user logs in or logs out. But when this happens, any screens other than (LoginScreen() and HomeScreen()) are not redirected to the proper screen.

I have a button to log out, this I will use intentionally for the example. On HomeScreen() and AnotherScreen(). When I press the Logout button on HomeScreen() my app redirects to LoginScreen(). **The problem is that when I try to log out of AnotherScreen(), it actually logs out but doesn't redirect to LoginScreen().**

main.dart

```
return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
    // execute others..
    final user = snapshot.data;
    if (user != null) {
      return HomeScreen();
    } else {
      return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
)
```

HomeScreen.dart

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
          child: Text('Signout'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go to AnotherScreen()")
          onPress: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AnotherScreen()));
          }
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

AnotherScreen.dart

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Another Screen')
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
          child: Text('Signout'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

It has taken me a lot to understand what is happening, maybe I do not understand how flutter works. So does each new screen behave independently and do i need to push the page manually?

Comment: yes of course you need to push pages manually, otherwise the user will just be logged but will happen in the UI.

Comment: @HiwaJalal But then why in LoginScreen and HomeScreen if the flow of redirecting the screens works automatically and is it not the same in those of more screens? You can expand your answer and so I can understand and mark it as appropriate, thanks.

Comment: do you have your project code inside github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that it is actually showing the `LoginScreen`, but only on the previous screen in the stack.

I would recommend trying this out inside your `AnotherScreen.dart`:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Another Screen')
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // This will remove screens until it reaches your home/login screen
            Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
            return FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
          },
          child: Text('Signout'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

---

If you do not want to remove the screens from the stack, you will probably need to add a `StreamBuilder` around your `AnotherScreen`:

```dart
return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
    final user = snapshot.data;
    if (user != null) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Another Screen')
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
                child: Text('Signout'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
);
```

---

PS: I have not tested it, let me know if this works for you.